# how to kill process other than system32

Tags: process, cmd, system32

i want to kill all processes which do not origin from System32 folder usindg CMD because it is slowing my computer and making other applications stop working.

Comment: Maybe try [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) with a filter.

Comment: yes but what do i write after or before taskkill? i dont know.

Comment: I don't know either. I wish I could be of more help.